# Logical consequences with allquantifiers and disjunctions

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I came across an example, which discusses whether F2 is a logical consequence of F1.

F1:= (∀x:ℕ[2]. p[x] ∨ q[x])

F2:= (∀x:ℕ[2]. p[x]) ∨ (∀x:ℕ[2]. q[x])

The answer is apparently no and the example given where F1 is true and F2 is false is:

p(0) = true,  p(1) = true,  p(2) = false

q(0) = false, q(1) = false, q(2) = true

**What is the difference between the two formulas?**
I don't understand, why F2 is false e.g. under the assignment p(0) = true and q(0) = false. Isn't it sufficient in the second case as well, if only one statement of the disjunction holds?

There is a similar example with existential quantifiers:

F := (∃x: p(x))∧(∃x: q(x))

G := (∃x: p(x)∧q(x))

There, if I understand it correctly, the difference is, that in G p and q have to hold for the same x value at the same time, whereas in F, x could have different values as long as those values each satisfy p and q. **Is that right?**

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: "What is the difference between the two formulas?" Very simple example: "For every number, either it is Odd or it is Even" vs "Either every number is Odd or every number is Even".

Comment: For the existential quantifier, consider "There is an Odd number and there is an Even number" vs "There is a number that is both Odd and Even".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand, why F2 is false e.g. under the assignment p(0) = true and q(0) = false. Isn't it sufficient in the second case as well, if only one statement of the disjunction holds?

$F2$ is $(\forall x.p(x)) \lor (\forall x.q(x))$

This statement is the disjunction of $\forall x.p(x)$ and $\forall x .q(x)$, and so it would be true if either $\forall x.p(x)$ or $\forall x.q(x)$ is true (or both).

But: $\forall x.p(x)$ is not true in the domain $\{0,1,2\}$ as indicated, because $p(2)$ is false.  And $\forall x.q(x)$ is also not true, because $q(0)$ is false. So, $F2$ is false.

Your reasoning in the quote above only applies to $F1$:  for every object in the domain $\{0,1,2\}$ it *is* true that they have either property $p$ or property $q$. But it is not true that either everything has property $p$, or that everything has property $q$.